# Can I have more than one consumer group in a single partition topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I know if I have more instances of the application using the same consumer group (application) than partitions some instances subscription will be idle.

But can I have more consumer groups (different applications) than the number of partitions?

Funny chatgpt and gemini give me a different answer

[gemini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4SZP.png)
[chatgtp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs5kj.png)

Comment: It should be easy to test this with the console consumer and the `--group` flag?

Answer (score 1):

There's no relation between number of consumer groups and partition number.
That's the design of Kafka, stored once -> consumed multiple time

So to answer your question, yes you can have multiple applications with different consumer groups more then your partitions number